# ADO: Excel: Is it possible to open recordset on table name?

Tags: excel, vba, ado, recordset

I have looked on the web but did not find any answer. So i am putting it here.

Code snippet: ( where case 1 is not working.. )

```
_bstr_t    strCnn(L"Provider='Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0';DataSource=C:\\Book.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR = YES\"");

hr = pConn->Open(strCnn, "", "", adConnectUnspecified); // success

**LPCSTR strQuery = "select * FROM Table1";          // case1: Not working**

LPCSTR strQuery = "select * FROM [Sheet1$]";       // case2: working

LPCSTR strQuery = "select * FROM [Sheet1$A1:D10]"; // case3: working

hr = pRst->Open(CComVariant(strQuery), _variant_t((IDispatch *)pConn, true),
                adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic,adCmdText); // fails for case 1
```

Is this possible in excel? or there is something wrong in the above code.

NOTE: I have tried this with Microsoft Access and binding recorset to table name works fine there.

Answer (score 3):

The short version is:

#### A 'Table' inserted into an Excel Spreadsheet is not visible as a table in SQL.

You need a named range, or a named worksheet, or the full address of the 'table' data range and headers; and the apparent existence of a named range associated with an Excel table is misleading.

---

I guess that needs some explanation, starting with:

#### What, exactly, is this 'Table1'?

It's not a named range, it's not a sheet, and it cannot be resolved to an Excel Range object by your SQL. To recap that:

- If you had created a named range, globally visible in the workbook,
  and called it 'Table1', it would be visible to your SQL query as
  **Table1**.
- If you had renamed the worksheet to 'Table1',  it would be visible to
  your SQL query as **Table1$**.
- If you had created a named range, local to the scope of a worksheet
  named 'Sheet1', and named it 'Table1', it would be visible to your
  SQL as **Sheet1$Table1**.

An Excel 'Table' is none of those things, so it isn't visible as a table to the database engine.

Yes, it shows up in the 'Name Manager' dialog for named ranges: but 'Table1' is not the name of a named range, nor a worksheet, nor does it specify a range with an address recognisable to SQL: and it needs to be one of those three things in order to be visible as a database table to the OLEDB and ODBC database drivers available for Excel.

The object you've created as 'Table1' is a **ListObject**, and you can interrogate it in the Excel VBA IDE's debug window as:

`Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Name`

So what you need is the address of the ListObject's range, and that's a simple matter of...

Actually, it isn't simple at all.

...The ListObject has a `DataBodyRange` property, which covers the rows of data below the header; and a `HeaderRowRange` which refers to the headers. Both, being ranges, have an address; and you'd need to `UNION` them to get a single address that your SQL can read as a named table.

Or use `Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").Sort.Rng.address` because every ListObject has a `Sort` object property, whether it's sorted or not; and the `Rng` property is the *entire* range, with a cavalier disregard for consistent object names and no hint as to the column or columns' address being sorted.

...And that information is useless for your question and your coding: there's nothing you can put into an SQL query that will parse the 'Table' object as a valid table.

You have to extract and parse the address of the full 'table' range before you run the SQL. The ADO and ODBC Excel drivers will work on a contiguous range address of the form '**SheetName$A1:Z1024**' but they have no ability to extract that address from the parent workbook of the Excel 'Table' object.

Apologies for the disappointing answer.

---

By the way, you *do* know that querying Excel with *any* of the available ODBC and OLEDB SQL drivers gives you a memory leak? At least, it does if you do it from VBA: I would advise you not to run this repeatedly unless you run Purify or a similar tool on your code and isolate the problem.

Comment: It appears a ListObject also has a range property which gives the full range.  So, Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Address works for me.

Comment: ListObjects are not a very well-implemented object but, if you're confident with the quirky interface, go for it. Be warned, though, that they'll slow down your workbook severely when you're using large and dynamic datasets.