# Insert a row in an Excel Recordset through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert some values on the last row of the recordset which in this case is an Excel file that serves as my database. I have the code below that works in inserting the value of the textbox to the last row of the excel recordset. However, it did not create a new table row where the value was inserted.

```
Sub CreaterRow()
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strConnect As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    strFile = "C:\Excel\Test.xlsx"
    strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile & _
    ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
    cnn.Open ConnectionString:=strConnect
    strSQL = "SELECT [ID] FROM [Sheet1$]"
    rst.Open Source:=strSQL, ActiveConnection:=cnn, CursorType:=adOpenForwardOnly, Options:=adCmdText

    With rst
        .AddNew
           .Fields("ID").Value = tbx_ID.Value 'Inserting this in the recordset did not create a new row
         .Update
    End with 

    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
End Sub
```

How can the table automatically create a new row that will include the value is inserted in the lastrow? Thank  you.

Comment: You do not call `Update` on your recordset

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was unable to paste  '.Update' My question remains the same.

Comment: You don't get any errors?

Comment: No I'm not getting any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.  You need to have the right cursor and lock type.

```
Sub CreaterRow()
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strConnect As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

    strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Data.xlsx"

    strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""" & strFile & _
                """;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
    cnn.Open ConnectionString:=strConnect
    strSQL = "SELECT [ID] FROM [Sheet1$]"

    rst.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

    With rst
        .AddNew
        .Fields("ID").Value = "ID00020"
        .Update
    End With

    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** if you're querying data from a Table/Listobject then appending records will not resize the list to include the added records.  See: [ADO: Excel: Is it possible to open recordset on table name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36855243/ado-excel-is-it-possible-to-open-recordset-on-table-name)

**EDIT2:** If you use a *named range* instead of a ListObject, then you can query it by name (instead of using the sheet name) and the range *will* adjust when you insert new rows.

Comment: It is working without errors, but still it's not creating a table row. Did your result created new table row

Comment: Yes  - added at the end of the existing data.

Comment: For me, the value was inserted and attached to the end of the data, but the table didn't create a new row. I will try to create a new table if that will work. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36855243/ado-excel-is-it-possible-to-open-recordset-on-table-name

Comment: D***. I highly appreciate you for providing insight. if you can please alter your answer that will reflect also the information in the link, then I will check your answer. So in sum, it's not possible to add a table row in this case, right?

Comment: I guess - I've not attempted anything to work around that apparent limitation.

Comment: The possibility may or may not exist. I will continue search then, time permits. Thanks.

Comment: If you use a named range instead of a listobject, then you can query it by name (instead of using the sheet name) and the range will adjust when you insert new rows.