# Open Excel table as DAO RecordSet for Appending

Tags: excel, vba, dao

I'm trying to update a table in an Excel file from DAO as if it were a Database table. Sounds like something that should be possible but I can't find any documentation about opening Excel with DAO.

I got as far as opening the file and getting a recordset handle but I'm seeing error 3027 "Cannot update. Database or object is read only." when I try to add to the recordset. One part of the problem is that I can see the sheet as a tabledef but I can't find the excel table in that sheet as an object. Maybe I don't know the proper syntax to open the table as a recordset.

The code I am using specifies dbOpenDynaset, like you would to make an Access table writable. Is what I am trying even possible?

The error occurs on ".AddNew":

```
Const dbOpenDynaset As Long = 2
Const dbAppendOnly As Long = 8
Const dbOptimistic As Long = 3

Public Sub OpenExcelAsDB(ByVal excelFile As String) 
    Dim fileExtension As String
    fileExtension = Right$(excelFile, Len(excelFile) - InStrRev(excelFile, "."))

    Dim connectionString As String
    Select Case fileExtension
    Case "xls"
        connectionString = "Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"
    Case "xlsx"
        connectionString = "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"
    Case "xlsb"
        connectionString = "Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"
    Case "xlsm"
        connectionString = "Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"
    Case Else
        connectionString = "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"
    End Select

    With CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")
        With .OpenDatabase(excelFile, False, False, connectionString)
            With .OpenRecordset("LogSheet$", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly, dbOptimistic) 
                .AddNew
                With .Fields()
                    .Item("errorNumber").Value = errorNumber
                    .Item("errorDescription").Value = errorDescription
                    .Item("customNote").Value = customNote
                    .Item("errorDate").Value = Now()
                    .Item("Username").Value = UserLogon
                    .Item("Computer").Value = ComputerName
                End With

                .Update
                .Close
            End With

            .Close
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Data Access Objects (DAO) is obsolete. The replacement was ActiveX Data Objects (ADO). The code needs to be rewritten using `ADODB.Connection` objects as seen in this question:
[Insert a row in an Excel Recordset through Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59867747/insert-a-row-in-an-excel-recordset-through-excel-vba)

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a pretty old tech stack, at this point in time.  I think it was around in the early 1990s and it certainly still persists, but the support seems to be dwindling.  So, with that caveat, you can try something like this.

```
Sub DAOFromExcelToAccess()
' exports data from the active worksheet to a table in an Access database
' this procedure must be edited before use
Dim db As Database, rs As Recordset, r As Long
    Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\FolderName\DataBaseName.mdb") 
    ' open the database
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TableName", dbOpenTable) 
    ' get all records in a table
    r = 3 ' the start row in the worksheet
    Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0 
    ' repeat until first empty cell in column A
        With rs
            .AddNew ' create a new record
            ' add values to each field in the record
            .Fields("FieldName1") = Range("A" & r).Value
            .Fields("FieldName2") = Range("B" & r).Value
            .Fields("FieldNameN") = Range("C" & r).Value
            ' add more fields if necessary...
            .Update ' stores the new record
        End With
        r = r + 1 ' next row
    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Personally, I would steer clear from these kinds of things, and focus on some kind of cloud tech stack.

Comment: Two problems: You are opening an old MDB file. The question is about using DAO to modify an Excel file. I can read from Excel files this way but I haven't been able to write to recordsets. I have no interest in putting my Excel files in the cloud. Likewise, SQL express is free on premise where Azure SQL costs an arm and a leg. The cloud is not right for everyone and you shouldn't be pushing big iron like IBM in the 90's.