# Updating Master file with new items from many files from folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master file and many 'sub' files for each leader with 2 sheets and the tables are all like(The other sheet is slightly different, but once I get this one, the other will be easy):

| Date | TLID | Action1 | Action2 | Action3 | More Actions... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20-05-2021 | AAA 111 | ABC 123 - Descr |  | BCA 321 - Descr |  |
| 21-05-2021 | BBB 222 |  | THX 654 - Descr |  | KLI 420 - Descr |

They may or may not be complete rows, as some actions may have one user in the column and some may have many, depending on the day. The Date and TLID will always have values. I believe the dates will be different. The 'sub' files will be updated as needed.

What I want to accomplish is to copy any newly added items from the 'sub' files for each user, and paste them into a Master file. I'm able to open up each file in a folder, but I'm stuck on how to filter the new items as some of the dates will be the same in each 'sub' file.

This is what I have to try and pull the new items, but it's not adding to the master file:

```
Set xlBook = ThisWorkbook
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets("Actions")
Set xlSheet2 = xlBook.Sheets("Action Codes")

filePath = fldrSel.SelectedItems(1)
ext = ".xls*"
file = Dir(filePath & "\", vbReadOnly)

Do While file <> ""
    Set srcBook = Workbooks.Open(filePath & "\" & file)
    For Each srcSheet In srcBook.Sheets
    If srcSheet.Name Like "Actions" Then
        srcSheet.Activate
        destRow = xlSheet.Cells(xlSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lstRow = srcSheet.Cells(srcSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lstColm = srcSheet.Cells(1, srcSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set destRng = xlSheet.Range("A2:K" & destRow)
        Set srcRng = srcSheet.Range(srcSheet.Cells(lstRow), srcSheet.Cells(lstColm))
        varSrc = srcSheet.Range("A2:K" & lstRow).Value
        varDest = xlSheet.Range("A2:K" & destRow).Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(varSrc)
            j = 1
            'blMtch = True
            Do While j <= UBound(varDest) And blMtch = True
                If varDest(j, 1) <> varSrc(i, 1) Then
                    blMtch = False
                    Exit Do
                End If
                j = j + 1
            Loop
            If blMtch = False Then
                x = x + 1
                srcSheet.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Copy
                xlSheet.Cells(x, 1).PasteSpecial
            End If
        Next i
                ElseIf srcSheet.Name Like "Action Codes" Then
        srcSheet.Activate
        destRow = xlSheet.Cells(xlSheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lstRow = srcSheet.Cells(srcSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lstColm = srcSheet.Cells(1, srcSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set destRng = xlSheet2.Range("A2:I" & destRow)
        Set srcRng = srcSheet.Range(srcSheet.Cells(lstRow), srcSheet.Cells(lstColm))
        varSrc = srcSheet.Range("A2:I" & lstRow)
        varDest = xlSheet.Range("A2:I" & lstRow)
        For i = 1 To UBound(varSrc)
            j = 1
            'blMtch = False
            Do While j <= UBound(varDest) And blMtch = True
                If varDest(j, 1) <> varSrc(i, 1) Then
                    blMtch = False
                    Exit Do
                End If
                j = j + 1
            Loop
            If blMtch = False Then
                x = x + 1
                srcSheet.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Copy
                xlSheet.Cells(x, 1).PasteSpecial
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    Next srcSheet
    srcBook.Close
    file = Dir
Loop
```

I hope I explained this well, and thank you for any help!

Comment: This sounds like a job for MSAccess. If everyone was just using the same database then you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: I agree, and I wish they were. My colleague mentioned a way for Excel to treat sheet like ADO recordsets with `qryData = "[" & table.Range.Worksheet.Name & "$" & Replace(table.Range.Address, "$", "") & "]"`

Comment: You can use ADODB to query excel files. This allows you to pull data without fully "opening" them in excel. You're opening them through the DB connector which bypasses all the excel junk and gives you the data. I wrote a short post about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091964/fast-way-to-query-listobject-vba/51106118#51106118

Comment: and another one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61198305/open-excel-table-as-dao-recordset-for-appending

Comment: awesome, I'l try them out. Did you eve find an answer for you second link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61198305/open-excel-table-as-dao-recordset-for-appending It seems we might have the same problem

Comment: just don't do it that way. You can pull data using ADO and then write it using native Excel methods. Better yet, pull the data in to MSAccess. Then you can export views from Access in to a new Excel document if the consumer wants that format. Now you have a database and you're one step closer to SQL (which is where you want to be).

Comment: Thank you! I wish people weren't so picky sometimes. It would make life way easier